# Only part of my if-else statement within my event listener is working

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Code newbie here. So I'm trying to make some changes to my rock paper scissors game. I want the score to be captured as well as display the text of the results on the page. The text used to display every time the button was clicked but once I added the +1 increment and the code to display the score on screen in real-time, the text doesn't display. I'm only testing this out on the 'rock' event listener first just to make sure it works.

```
//Selects the classes .rock .paper .scissors
const rock = document.querySelector(".rock")
const paper = document.querySelector(".paper")
const scissors = document.querySelector(".scissors")

//new div under results
const results = document.getElementById("results");

//new items
let itemRock = document.createElement('h3');
let itemPaper = document.createElement('h3');
let itemScissors = document.createElement('h3');
    
//variable for computerPlay() function to be printed to #results
itemRock.textContent = 'You have chosen rock!';
itemPaper.textContent = 'You have chosen paper!';
itemScissors.textContent = 'You have chosen scissors!';

//Player + computer score for count purposes
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

rock.addEventListener('click', function() {
    computerPlay();
    if(computerPlay() === 'paper') {
        itemRock.textContent = 'You have chosen rock and the computer has chosen paper.' + 'You lose, paper beats rock! Try again';
        computerScore += 1;
         document.getElementById("computer-score").innerText = computerScore;
    } else if (computerPlay() === 'rock') {
        itemRock.textContent = 'You have chosen rock and the computer has chosen rock.' +  'Its a draw, try again';
    } else {
        itemRock.textContent = 'You have chosen rock and the computer has chosen 
        scissors. ' + 'You win! Rock beats scissors.';
        playerScore += 1;
        document.getElementById("player-score").innerText = playerScore;
    }
    return 'rock';  
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="choice">

<button type="button" class="rock">Rock</button>
<button type="button" class="paper">Paper</button>
<button type="button" class="scissors">Scissors</button>

</div>
    <div id="results">
</div>
<p>Player Score: <a id="player-score">0</a></p>
<p>Computer Score: <a id="computer-score">0</a></p>
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're calling the computerPlay() function each time going through the if/else statements. That will return different values, supposing that computerPlay() returns either rock, paper, or scissors randomly. One easy thing you can do is to store the returned value in a variable like this

```
let computersHand = computerPlay();
```

and then use this variable when going through the if/else statements

```
if (computersHand === 'rock') {
    // ...
} else if (computersHand === 'paper') {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

If you don't want to store the returned value into a variable for whatever reason, you can use a switch statement

```
switch (computerPlay()) {
   case 'rock':
       // ...
       break;
   case 'paper':
       // ...
       break;
   case 'scissors':
       // ...
       break;
}
```

I recommend you read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

Comment: Yup, the poster above said the same thing, that I am calling my function more than once. I had no idea that was the case with if-else statements. I didnt know that the if-else actually calls it haha. I'm trying to use 'switch' more often just to make it more readable. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

You should call the `computerPlay` function once

```
rock.addEventListener('click', function() {
    
    const result = computerPlay();
    
    if (result) {
         itemRock.textContent = 'You have chosen rock and the computer has chosen paper. 
         ' + 'You lose, paper beats rock! Try again';
         computerScore += 1;
         document.getElementById("computer-score").innerText = computerScore;
    } else if(result) {
         itemRock.textContent = 'You have chosen rock and the computer has chosen rock. 
         ' +  'Its a draw, try again';
    } else {
         itemRock.textContent = 'You have chosen rock and the computer has chosen 
         scissors. ' + 'You win! Rock beats scissors.';
         playerScore += 1;
         document.getElementById("player-score").innerText = playerScore;
    }
  
    return 'rock';  
})
```

Calling the `computerPlay` function like this

```
computerPlay();
if (computerPlay() === 'paper')
```

makes no sense, cause you call it's twice (computer plays two times in one click)

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. I didn't think the start of the 'if' statement would call the computerPlay. Actually had no idea. Ty for the help, it clears a lot up